# Viewing design in different sized browsers?

Tags: responsive-design

I've just starting reading about responsive design and I want to start learning more and more about it.

The first thing that has occurred to me is how to actually view your work in different screen sizes.

Is there a standard tool that people use on there computers to simulate there work on all different devices?? Or do you just check your work on the different devices??

Currently I've just been moving my browser to approximate sizes and it feels really unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, if you press [F12], on the top left corner, you have an icon which look like a mobile phone, then in your page, you can select the device model, and the screen resolution

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is using chrome standard practice?? or do people use other tools.